# inline sql query error

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am writing this basic sql statement in proc sql yet SAS throws me an error.

```
    proc sql;
select interest from
(select * from project.data_model
order by ethnicity desc, satscore desc);
quit;
```

ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, ','.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored

I know I can write interest in the inner query itself but I was just giving a try using inline query.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you receive is not very helpful.  The problem you have is that `order by` is not valid within an in-line view, which is effectively what your subquery is creating.  To solve this you need to put the `order by` statement outside of the subquery.

```
proc sql;
select interest from
(select * from project.data_model)
order by ethnicity desc, satscore desc;
quit;
```